# The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to follow the example in a pluralsight videos

https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app&author=shawn-wildermuth&name=aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app-m7&clip=8&mode=live&start=2

When I am trying to complete the Api to add the coordinates I am having the error:

The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is happening on the following class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Moran.Services
{
    public class CoordService
    {
        private ILogger<CoordService> _logger;

        public CoordService(ILogger<CoordService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<CoordServiceResult> Lookup(string location)
        {
            var result = new CoordServiceResult()
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = "Undetermined failures while looking up coordinates"
            };
            //Lookup Coordinates
            var bingKey = Startup.Configuration["AppSettings:BingKey"];
            var encodedName = WebUtility.UrlEncode(location);
            var url = $"http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={encodedName}&key={bingKey}";

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

            // Read out the results
            // Fragile, might need to change if the Bing API changes
            var results = JObject.Parse(json);
            var resources = results["resourceSets"][0]["resources"];
            if (!resources.HasValues)
            {
                result.Message = $"Could not find '{location}' as a location";
            }
            else
            {
                var confidence = (string)resources[0]["confidence"];
                if (confidence != "High")
                {
                    result.Message = $"Could not find a confident match for '{location}' as a location";
                }
                else
                {
                    var coords = resources[0]["geocodePoints"][0]["coordinates"];
                    result.Latitude = (double)coords[0];
                    result.Longitude = (double)coords[1];
                    result.Success = true;
                    result.Message = "Success";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This is happening when I try to add

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

Any Idea why this is happening?

I cannot find any reason why it doesn't compile....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpClient` class resides in `System.Net.Http` namespace, which is in `System.Net.Http.dll`. To use this class in your ASP.NET 5 project,You need to add `System.Net.Http` to the `"dependencies"` section of the json data inside your  `project.json` file

```
  "dependencies": {    
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",

    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23409"

  },
```

`4.0.1-beta-23409` is the latest version as of this writing. Visual studio  intellisense will give you multiple available versions  and you can pick the latest/stable.

After making this change, when you save the file, It will do a **dnu restore** (*which will usually download the necessary packages as needed*) and add a reference to the ***System.Net.Http*** assembly. You can add a using statement in your class and start using `HttpClient` class.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
public class SomeClass
{
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
     var client = new HttpClient();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This really helped me out.